# Expanding a child div outside of a container div equally on boths sides with margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

Say I have a div that is containing a child div. The container div is set to `margin: 0` auto so when the width is increased, the div expands on both sides. If the div inside this container was also set to `margin: 0` auto, is there a way to have this div expand beyond its container div and reach to the right and to the left equally?

The following example shows that when width of the .background is increased beyond the width of container, its size only increases from the right and not from both sides.

the css and html:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.background {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.content {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "background">
    <div class = "content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DpYGm/2/

This is all an attempt to get a banner graphic background image to span the body width of a page but still have the content on the inside of the page to remain the same.

Comment: So you want `div.background` to be the full width of the page? even though it is the child of a containing block `div.container` with width of 600px?

Comment: Why don't you just place the background image on `div.container`?

Comment: @MarcAudet that wouldn't solve my problem. I don't want to change the css of the parent element.

Comment: do not set a width for the bounding container. use min-width as a starting point, then let it float with the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you want the `background` div to stick out by 50px on each side. You could do this in your CSS:

```
.background {
    margin: 0 -50px 0 -50px;
    background-color: #00F;
}
```

A full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style media="all">

      .container {
        width: 500px;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 400px; /* for illustration */
      }
      .background {
        margin: 0 -50px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      .content {
        width: 200px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "background">
        <div class = "content">
          content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: works like a charm in Chrome. I'm gonna test this answer on my webpage and in a few browsers then get back to you.

Comment: Cool. It's pretty bulletproof, I think you'll find. :-)

Comment: Wonderful. Works in IE7, 8, 9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Answer (score 3):

For sure:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.background {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.content {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yBcpu/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is a more semantic way to achieve this depending on your reasoning:

```
.container {
    background: green url(../path-to-image.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height:300px;
}

.content {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Stick your background image on .container with position top center.

http://jsfiddle.net/DpYGm/5/